# spyder keep window open after execution?

Tags: python, spyder

How do you prevent spyder IDE from automatically closing the window after executing a program?

Windows 7
Anaconda 2.7 package.

I don't have this issue with geany. I'm sure I need some sort of command in the compiling options but I've googled for a couple hours and haven't found anything about this extremely EXTREMELY simple problem.

My test code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(1)
```

I want to see all of the 1s sitting there in front of me until I click close.